# Sharepoint: Communication between WebPart and silverlight control

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, web-parts

Is there any way to send notifications from the webpart to silverlight control hosted in the same webpart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JavaScript using the [HTML DOM Bridge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076(VS.95).aspx) in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a blog about a web part pattern I've developed for Silverlight Web Part communication:

http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.com/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-silverlight-web-part.html